# Synchronize Staging Server and Live Server

Tags: mysql, php, performance, synchronization

We have staging and live server at our office. Where Live code and DB changes are far more advanced than staging one.This application developed under php and DB is mysql.

Earlier we used to work in staging then we upload that on live server . From some months we are working in live for making things work faster and set up the application . But from that time staging server is not synced to live server i.e live server has advanced code and many DB changes than Staging . Now we want to synchronize the staging server with live server.

Answer (score 1):

I would rebuild the server from scratch using the same documentation that I have for production. or more likely I would get puppet to do it for me.

If you don't have that documentation or automation, now is the perfect opportunity to look into doing it.